# Error al hacer foreach laravel 8

Tags: laravel

Hola quiero hacer una pregunta, estoy programando en laravel 8 estoy haciendo un foreach cuando realizo un registro de usuario nuevo me sale el siguiente error en la vista donde tengo el foreach

Undefined variable $posts (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto1\resources\views\paginas\mascota.blade.php)

lo que tengo en el controlador es esto

```html
    $posts = RegistrarMascota::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->latest()->get();
        return view('paginas.mascota', array("posts"=>$posts));
```

lo que tengo en mi vista es esto

```html
    @foreach ($posts as $key => $value)

  <div class="card mb-4">
         

                     <div class="card-body">
                     
                      <img src="{{asset('storage').'/'.$value->Foto}}"  class="card-img-top">
             <br>  
             <br>    
                        
<h5 class="card-title">{{$value->RazaMascota}} </h5>
<BR>
<p class="clard-text">
 
{{$value->RazaMascota}}

<a href="">Leer Mas </a>




    </p>

    <p class="text-muted mb-0">
<em>

 
</em>
<p>{{ $value->RazaMascota }}</p>


    </p>

                </div>
            </div>

@endforeach
```

no se porque del error me pueden ayudar

Comment: Tengo una pregunta: Si necesitas el último (que es la única razón que se me ocurre para que uses `latest`) de los registros, ¿por qué usas get y no first?

Answer (score 0):

Cambia `get()` por `first()` e intenta pasar los datos de otra forma a la vista.

```
$posts = RegistrarMascota::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->latest()->first();
return view('paginas.mascota')->with('posts', $posts);
```

Comment: me funciono siii

Comment: Si la respuesta te fue de utilidad recuerda marcarla como mejor respuesta, eso ayudará a más personas con tu misma pregunta en el futuro. [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas#:~:text=Para%20marcar%20una%20respuesta%20como,la%20respuesta%2C%20en%20cualquier%20momento.)

Answer (score 0):

El error esta en como intentas enviar los datos a la vista, en la línea:

```
return view('paginas.mascota', array("posts"=>$posts));
```

`$posts` ***no esta llegando a la vista***, entonces ***no esta definida***.

Puedes enviar la variable a la vista de la siguiente forma:

```
return view('paginas.mascota', [
    'posts' => $posts,
]);
```

o de esta otra:

```
return view('paginas.mascota')
    ->with('posts', $posts);
```